# Disabled body scrolling while focus is in div, after scrolling div and re-enabling overflow:auto body scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a scrollable `<div>` inside my body that I want the user to be able to scroll. However, when the div reaches the top/bottom the entire page begins to scroll which is not desired.

I have managed to stop the body from scrolling by including the following inside the div tags:

```
onmouseover="document.body.style.overflow='hidden';"
onmouseout="document.body.style.overflow='auto';"`
```

For the most part this works, since I want the user to be able to scroll the body if focus is not inside of the scrollable div.

The issue is that if I make a scroll in the div as soon as I exit the mouse cursor from the div (such that the body overflow is set again to auto) the body begins to scroll as though the scroll event has a delayed propagation from the scrollable div (to the body).

I'm a novice web developer, any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

So I tried to reproduce the issue but wasn't able to do it in both Firefox and Chrome (see snippet). Can you create a snippet where you're able to reproduce the issue? What browser are you using?

```css
div.first {
  height: 200vh;
}
div.first > div {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
div.first > div > div {
  background: orange;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 300px;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div onmouseover="document.body.style.overflow='hidden';"
onmouseout="document.body.style.overflow='auto';">
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That being said, maybe your problem occurs when you move the cursor out of the scrollable div while you are still scrolling. In the script below I set `onmouseout="setTimeout(function(){ document.body.style.overflow='auto'; }, 500);"` which means that after the cursor leaves the div a timeout of .5 seconds start before the body can be scrolled again.

```css
div.first {
  height: 200vh;
}
div.first > div {
  height: 70vh;
  overflow: scroll;
}
div.first > div > div {
  background: orange;
  height: 200vh;
  width: 300px;
}
div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div onmouseover="document.body.style.overflow='hidden';"
onmouseout="setTimeout(function(){ document.body.style.overflow='auto'; }, 500);">
    <div>test</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are correct that the problem only occurs when the cursor is moved out of the scrollable div while still scrolling. It seems to take a really long time for the scrolling to complete. To clarify the scroll position is reached but the scroll bar (inside div) stays for a long time, and if i mouse out while the scroll bar is still there, the scroll is propagated to the body (unless I set the timeout as you mentioned). Problem now is that I need to set a long timeout >1 sec. Do you know how I can make the scroll end inside the div sooner? Tried googling but couldnt come up with anything.

Comment: Better yet, is it possible to kill the scroll when i mouseout? The timeout is causing some problems (like if I go out of the div and then back in (before exit timeout), the overflow will actually get set to auto (instead of hidden) one the timer fires (and im still inside the div).